# What web service on lighttpd

Tags: soap, lighttpd

I have to do web service + web page on openwrt device. From web page I can send communications to a program which is running on the device, so I need to build web service and I don't know which to chose for lighttpd web server, I don't know if Soap Lite is compatible with openwrt+lighttpd.

Comment: Are you asking how do I code and run a webservice on an openwrt device running lighthttpd?

Answer (score 1):

Soap Lite is a "collection of Perl modules" for perl. You can use the cgi extension on lighttpd to use perl. So yes, it would work with lighttpd. The question is if your router has enough processing power to support lighttpd + cgi.